# Is saying "it has someone as its writer" correct?

Tags: expression-choice

If someone writes a book for example, can you say "it has Michael as its writer"?

Or is it necessary to say "its writer is Michael"?

There are possible connotations for each form? (like for example that in the first sentence more people wrote it).

Comment: From an objective point of view, I don't agree with this usage. It's grammatically correct but sounds stunted. "Michael wrote it" is clearer and more concise. However, when used more prozaically, it can be accepted, I think. E.g. "If the Harry Potter saga had had George R R Martin as its writer, Hermione would have been naked or dead by the second chapter."

Comment: Normally one would use "author" rather than "writer".  (Though it's more idiomatic to say "written by" than "authored by".)

Comment: If the book was written by Michael, then the best way to express that is by saying "the book was written by Michael". Yes, of course I can instead go and say "composed has been this scripture by none other than the one whom as its writer it has, and Michael be his name for y'all to know" but there is no reason whatsoever for me to do so short of communicating to my readers that I'm the ponciest ponce that ever ponced past a poncing parlour.

Comment: Very funny comment, now I understand it better =P

Comment: Prozaically as the adverb associated with prozac?

Comment: @Flater can you adduce evidence that supports your "objective point of view"? When you say it  "sounds stunted", can you please provide from what reference point you say that? For example, are you saying that as a native speaker or professor of linguistics or just what? It's unclear on what basis you say it "sounds stunted." Whatever the case, don't you mean "subjective point of view"?

Comment: @Clare: Rereading my comment 5 months after writing it, I agree that the first sentence should have been drastically changed. However, I do think you're nitpicking at the "sounds stunted". I think RegDwight's comment explains it best, _"there is no reason whatsoever for me to do so short of communicating to my readers that I'm the ponciest ponce that ever ponced past a poncing parlour"_. Which is exactly what I mean by "sounds stunted", and I don't quite agree that this needs further elaboration for it to be understood.

Comment: Was just interested in your background  because it doesn't sound stunted to me (college educated native speaker of American English; have lived in 11 states of the US, including places where standard English is rarely heard). @Flater

Comment: @Clare: Wait, you're telling me that people can have different opinions on subjective topics? This is groundbreaking! Oh, wait, no, [my mistake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subjective). (as to your English street cred, this is not a d*** measuring competition)

Comment: Was just interested in your background. @Flater thought since I was asking about yours, I would share mine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say

> "The book has Michael as its writer."

Here's a somewhat more natural or realistic use of this structure:

> The movie idea, with X as its director, and Y as its producer, seemed like a proposition that couldn't fail.